# Segmentation fault occurs when add mysql client libarary

Tags: c, mysql

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<mysql/mysql.h>
int main()
{
  char *tempry;
  tempry =  (char *) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
  sprintf(tempry,"hello");
  printf("\n%s\n",tempry);
  /* Here i can use mysql connectivity code */
  return 0;
}
```

when i use this  `gcc test.c -o test -g` gcc compilation command then it will give me output

```
hello
```

and if i used this `gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient  test.c -o test -g` line then it will give me `segmenation fault error` in this line

```
tempry =  (char *) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: you don't need to typecast malloc return, use without (char*)

Comment: The code you post without any sql stuff is fine(if not talking about length check or free or something like that), something went wrong elsewhere.

Comment: put -l options at the end of the command line: I.e. gcc -g -o test test.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient

Comment: @Marian V does'nt work

Comment: Have you checked that your mysql library is accessible and not corrupted? You might check the source as well to see if there is some initialization is going on which fails. Maybe a missing include or something that fails to initialize something when the lib is loaded?

Comment: I had checked my mysql library is not corrupted and it works fine in other programs i can check this code in both server and local pc

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html follow the procedure and compile example code given in this site and then add your code.

Comment: Check the output of `mysql_config --cflags --libs`, and compare that to what you're actually passing to gcc. Also check my answer: simply add `mysql_config --cflags --libs` to your gcc command, using back-ticks will fill in the correct paths and params

Comment: `gcc -I/usr/local/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient test.c -o test -g` post full code with mysql connectivity.

Answer (score -1):

check your `mysql_real_connect()`. You probably passing `NULL` value to `mysql_real_connect()`.

`mysql_init()` return `NULL` when it fails. then you may passing this NULL to `mysql_real_connect()` so it leads to `segmentation fault`.

[mysql_init() Reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-init.html)

Comment: That's just a wild stab in the dark. OP didn't post any code that shows that this is the problem. For I know, it could be the OP has written something like `MYSQL *db = mysql_init(NULL); if (!db) fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed"); mysql_close(db);` <-- no braces, hence connection is closed on success, too and the code that follows is causing the segfault

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem this was one my error when i using `mysql` API. His compilation method is proper, So i assumed this might be the problem.

Comment: He's passing the paths to the lib, true, but he's not passing any cflags to gcc, that's why I suggested to the op to use `mysql_config --libs --cflags` instead.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you are right he is not passing `cflags`. But for `cflags` compiler has to give warning, he not mention anything about the warning.

Comment: That's why I also suggested adding `-Wall` to his compile command ;-P I've been active on this site for close to 2 years now, enough time to realize that not everyone mentions all the warnings/errors he's getting... especially those that obviously encounter issues when they _add_ a mysql dependency and don't include any code showing _how_ they use the mysql C API :)